# Can I use a gas oven spring form in my electric oven?

Tags: oven, gas

I have ordered a spring form online. The package arrived and on the packaging it says "especially for gas ovens".

I don't have a gas oven, but an electric one where I can set many different types of heat. Can I still safely use the form or should I return it? What is the difference between a gas oven form and a 'normal' form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that it's designed to conduct less heat from the bottom.

Many gas ovens have the flue in the bottom and the heating is only from below in the oven. To make things more even, most electric ovens have an element at the top and one on the bottom.

Speaking of bottom, the bottom line is that you should be ok. If you find the bottom of you cake not being done very well, move the form to a lower rack next time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean a spring form pan, often used for cheesecakes for example:

[image]

There is absolutely no reason that the type of oven would matter.  That seems to be very odd marketing copy.